# Scraping empty fields

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I need to extract all values, including the empty fields from the table, but the problem is that extract method skips empty fields. How can I collect those empty fields or replace them with something else?

Here is my expression for Scrapy shell:

```
row = response.xpath('//*[@class="apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA"]//tr//td//text()').extract()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scraping empty fields from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332368/scraping-empty-fields-from-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath selector here selects `text()` values:

```
'//*[@class="apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA"]//tr//td//text()'
```

What you want to do is select `td` values and iterate over them:

```
items = []
rows = response.xpath('//*[@class="apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA"]//tr//td')
for row in rows:
    text = ''.join(row.xpath('.//text()').extract())
    items.append(text)
```

Now even if there is no text your code will append an empty string to your item list. Doing this with xpath alone is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: That worked, thank you.But, the only problem is, that it misses links in td.How can it be fixed?